# Customizing email notifications when someone added a comment to a file

Tags: plone

I'd like to customize the text sent from the default Comment action of Plone, especially the link sent when someone comments on a file.  Current behavior is that the link launches the file itself. The behavior I'd like to see is to take the reader to be able to see the comment entered.

I've been trying to find the template script for the message via both ZMI and the Zope file system but couldn't locate the message template.

---

.... Example of Default Message ....

Someone added a comment on your File:
Test.

If you are the author of this item, we recommend that you read the comment,
and update the documentation accordingly if required - then remove the comment.

If further clarification is needed, reply to the comment, and the person who
made the comment will get a notification like this, and will likely give you
more details.

To view the new comment, visit:
http://bestkey.middlewaygroup.com/products/Test.ppt

--
Site Administrator

Comment: When asking for help with software, you should always provide the versions of the software and any add-ons you are using.

Comment: Plone Version is 3.3.5 and no add-ons. Thanks.

Comment: By comment I assume you mean the discussion at the bottom of the page.  I thought Plone 3 didn't send emails for discussion items?

Comment: I meant the Add Comment button at the bottom of a content type like Page. Evidently, because I had installed PHC, the Add Comment action caused a notification to be sent to the creator of the content.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [plone.app.discussion](http://pypi.python.org/plone.app.discussion) which is the new commenting system for Plone 4.1 and also available as an add-on product for Plone 3.3.

With p.a.discussion you can register a custom event subscriber that is fired when a new comment is added:

```
<subscriber
      for="plone.app.discussion.interfaces.IComment
           zope.app.container.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent"
      handler=".mycustomsubscriber.notify_user"
      />
```

You have to put a "notify_user" function inside a "mycustomsubscriber.py" file which can contain arbitrary Python code that sends a custom email.

See http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.discussion/trunk/plone/app/discussion/notifications.zcml and http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.discussion/trunk/plone/app/discussion/comment.py for examples.

If the old Plone commenting system comments provide an interface like IComment it should work similarly. Though, I think it does not provide such an interface, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it didn't - I couldn't find any way to tie a subscriber into it when I tried in the early days of Plone 3, though I haven't looked since.

Answer (score 1):

The module you are looking for is:

- **Products.PloneHelpCenter.skins.plone_help_center.discussion_notify_template.pt**

which you can override with [z3c.jbot](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/z3c.jbot/0.6.3). Or in the ZMI, customize:

- **portal_skins/plone_help_center/discussion_notify_template.pt**

(And, you must have at least one add-on installed, [Products.PloneHelpCenter](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PloneHelpCenter/4.0b3) because this message is from that add-on).

Comment: I guess the questioner cross posted.  http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Customizing-email-notifications-when-someone-81495.S.66911426

Comment: You are right I did install plone_help-center.  
I replaced the tal expression from 

<span i18n:name="url" tal:replace="comment_on_object/absolute_url" /> 

to 

<span i18n:name="url" tal:replace = " string: ${comment_on_object/absolute_url}/view" />  and it worked.